# Jackson ObjectMapper to process JSON and non-JSON inputs

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

## TL;DR

How can Jackson's `ObjectMapper` be made to work for deserializing an object when sometimes the input is serialized JSON and sometimes it is a non-JSON string?

## Details

I'm a Java/Jackson noob and have been banging my head against this all day.

I'm working in the context of a system that user ObjectMapper to deserialize inputs. I'm familiar with the Jackson annotations to make that work. And there's no problem when the input is serialized JSON.

The problem is I'm being provided a variety of inputs, some of which are not serialized JSON. I've seen answers related to polymorphic deserialization in which the serialized JSON may come in one of a variety of forms. That doesn't address the issue of how to handle input that is not serialized JSON at all.

I've tried using `@JsonDeserialize` to specify custom deserializers that extend `StdDeserializer` and `JsonDeserializer`. The problem in both cases is the `JsonParser` passed into the `deserialize` or `deserializeWithType` methods processes the input string before reaching my code, and so in the case of a non-JSON input the result is a `JsonParseException`.

So, is there a way to handle this? I'm working in the context of a larger system that expects `ObjectMapper` to do the work and, if possible, I'd like not to change that aspect of the system.

Comment: Can you provide an example input?

Comment: "example input" or alternatively '{ "example": "input" }'

Comment: @kkrian , if the input has `'{` and `}'`, use JSON approach, or else dont. Does this solve your need?

Comment: That is what I'm realizing. There's no way to specialize a deserializer within the Jackson way of doing things that would accept a non-JSON string as input. Yes?

Comment: @kkurian, JSON is a well defined format and `Jackson` knowing that parse it. When payload does not fit to format `Jackson` throws one from many exception he prepared for broken types of payload. What do you actually want to do when format is not a valid `JSON`? Create a mock object, parse it somehow, something other? When you use `ObjectMapper` you have limited access to payload. In your case probably much better approach would be to use [Jackson Streaming API](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api). Using it, you can read token by token and try to distinguish what kind of payload is